# making a perfect alignment with text out and in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, vertical-alignment

I need to perfectly align "text number one" and "text number two". Second text is inside a table. I need it to be that way to make my program work with functions I'll add later. I'm having a bad time with vertical-align coz it gives me different results depending on the browser I use. Am I doing something wrong or is this the kind of things that each browser gives different results.

The alignment is perfect using Microsoft Edge and IE10.
It doesn't fully align using Chrome, Mozilla and Opera.

The code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body style="font-size:18pt"><br><br>

    <span>  text number one

        <table style="margin:0; padding:0; border:0; border-spacing:0; vertical-align:text-bottom; display:inline-table">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:0">
                    text number two
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That hardly seems to be tabular data, so you should not use a table in the first place. _“I need it to be that way to make my program work with functions I'll add later”_ – if you haven’t even written those functions yet, then you should be able to work with an HTML structure that makes more sense semantically to begin with. And it would probably solve your alignment problem automatically. (If you actually have a real valid reason to use a table, then please describe what you are trying to achieve in more detail.)

Comment: according to my knowledge on CSS the texts should align... question is.. is the browser not showing what it's supposed to be shown... like I said some browsers do align it and some others won't... how do you make those texts align in all browsers in case I'm doing something wrong with my code...And yes I need it to be a table. The functions are already written, but it's a very large program and those functions are not the point of my question anyway.

Comment: Might be due to default margins/paddings applied to the table elements. Use your browser’s dev tools to investigate.

Comment: I would delete the span tag. It forces a horizontal (same line) alignment of all objects between the tags. It seem like you should build a full table. They are fussy about details but will give you what you want. Right now I see 1/2 a table and not sure that will work.

Comment: Why not make it a full table. I see 1/2 table and not sure how it will work with all browsers. The 'span' tag is only for inline elements.

Comment: Sparky, I defined the table as inline-table so it works like a span too. Johannes told me how to fix it anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `vertical-align:baseline;`, but on the `td`, not on the `table` (and delete `vertical-align:text-bottom;` from the `table` tag).

Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOpzdK

Comment: you got it, man... thanks a million... works perfect in all browsers

Comment: @Pablo Hi Pablo, you are welcome! If it works, please mark my answer as correct